# Parsing HTML using JSoup

Tags: jsoup

I want to parse out the description on [this](http://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/catalog/PIA16465) Nasa page, the text at the bottom of the page

How can I do this?

Comment: Read the page with jsoup, and then write code to navigate to the appropriate area and pull out the text. If Java is not your cup of tea, consider Beautiful Soup instead.

Comment: I not a java expert, nor android, not HTML. I did some reading.  If it's simple to do, I'm looking for sample code.

Comment: http://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/catalog/PIA16465

Answer (score 0):

First you need to connect to the page and parse this into a `Document` (make shure you import the Jsoup one), then you can use the [Selector API](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) to select whatever you need.

**Here's an example:**

```
// Connect to page and parse html into a 'Document'
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/catalog/PIA16465").get();


for( Element element : doc.select("p") )    // Select all 'p'-Tags and loop over them
{
    if( element.hasText() )                 // Check if the element has text (since there are some empty too)
    {
        System.out.println(element.text()); // print the element's text
    }
}
```

---

### -- Edit --

```
for( Element element : doc.select("dd p") ) // Or: "dd > p"
{
    if( element.hasText() )
    {
        System.out.println(element.text());
        break;
    }
}
```

Instead of the loop you could use something like this:

```
Element firstTag = doc.select("dd p").first();
```

This will give you the first p-Tag after a dd-Tag. But here it won't work because there are many empty p-tags which match it. However you can use a regex selector (see link above) to solve this, but for the first the loop is much easier to understand.

Comment: Ah, thats my problem.  I have Jsoup and w3c.dom.  How do I distinguish between the two?

Comment: ah, I just fully qualify it.  And now your loop works!  ollo, Thanks!!

Comment: Now, how would I find the first "p" tage after the first "dd" tag?  That's the text I want.